# Getting "Parse Error: Header overflow" but headers are <8KB

Tags: node.js, axios

Hi I'm encountering an issue when sending an axios GET request with headers. The error is indicating that the headers I'm specifying are too large, and when googling around I'm seeing that node has a default max header size of 8KB (that can be manually overridden). As far as I can tell though, the headers that I'm sending shouldn't be exceeding that byte limit. When I paste the text into a byte calculator it's always showing less than 3KB.

Here's the console output when logging the error.

[image: console logged error]

And here's the `error.toJSON()` output:

```
{
  message: 'Parse Error: Header overflow',
  name: 'Error',
  description: undefined,
  number: undefined,
  fileName: undefined,
  lineNumber: undefined,
  columnNumber: undefined,
  stack: 'Error: Parse Error: Header overflow\n' +
    '    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:469:22)\n' +
    '    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)\n' +
    '    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:295:12)\n' +
    '    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:271:9)\n' +
    '    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:212:10)\n' +
    '    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)',
  config: {
    url: 'https://pinterest.com/me',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      cookie: 'csrf=<32 CHARACTER CSRF TOKEN>;_pinterest_sess=<1156 CHARACTER SESSION VARIABLE>;',
      'x-csrftoken': '<32 CHARACTER CSRF TOKEN>',
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_3_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Electron/11.3.0 Safari/537.36'
    },
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    data: undefined
  },
  code: 'HPE_HEADER_OVERFLOW'
}
```

Am I missing something here? What's causing the headers to exceed the 8KB limit? Can someone help me troubleshoot?

Comment: were you able to fix this? i wasnt able to

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with the request headers. It was the response headers returned from pinterest.